# JSON list with JavaScriptSerializer in C#

Tags: c#, json, list

I want to end up with a JSON object like this:

```
{ "somefield" : ["a", "b", "c"] }
```

I tried

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                        { 
                            somefield  = ["a", "b", "c"]
                        });
```

but I get a syntax error (Syntax Error, ',' expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `new` keyword

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
              {
                  somefield = new[] { "a", "b", "c" }
              });
```